# Conditional cumulative sum in SAS

Tags: sas, conditional-statements, cumulative-sum

I have been searching the solution a while, but I couldn't find any similar question in SAS in communities.

I have the following table in SAS. I need to get the cumulative value by **Date**. Most importantly, I need the cumulative value starts from new once it exceeds **10**.

```
Date            Number 
01/01/2017       3
01/01/2017       1
01/01/2017       3
01/01/2017       4
01/01/2017       6
01/01/2017       8
02/01/2017       6
02/01/2017       3
02/01/2017       5
02/01/2017       7
03/01/2017       4
03/01/2017       3 
   ...           ...
```

I need my output table looks like this. Just one more column shows the cumulative values.

```
Date            Number     cumulative
01/01/2017       3            3
01/01/2017       1            4        
01/01/2017       3            7
01/01/2017       4            4             <---- (starts from new)   
01/01/2017       6            10
01/01/2017       8            8
02/01/2017       6            6
02/01/2017       3            9
02/01/2017       5            5
02/01/2017       7            7             <---- (starts from new) 
03/01/2017       4            3
03/01/2017       3            7
   ...           ...          ...
```

Would someone be able to assist with this.

Thanks

Comment: Please show what code you have tried.  Are you using DATA step with RETAIN?  Also, looks like a typo where cumulative for second-to-last row should be 4, not 3.

Comment: If you post a better explanation of what you want, you will definitely get an answer. This is definitely a puzzle someone will help with if you make the rules better defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like (untested):

```
data out;
  set in;
  by date; * Assumes sorted by date;
  retain cumulative;
  if first.date or cumulative+number > 10 then do;
    cumulative = 0;
  end;
  cumulative = cumulative + number;
run;
```

should work...